# BASH SPLIT STRING into own OUTPUT

Tags: string, bash, split

how can i split this string

22:45:47.349293 00:00:00:00:00:00 > 20:cf:30:39:60:69, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.0.100.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300

into ONE line like this

TIME FIRSTMACADDRESS FIRSTIP

22:45:47   00:00:00:00:00:00   192.168.0.1

?

my actual result is

TIME: 22:45:47

MAC: 00:c0:26:00:bc:14 IP: 192.168.0.1

with this code

```
    cat $TEMPDATA | while read line
    do
    if [ "$line" != "" ]; then

    set -- $line

    echo TIME: "$line" | awk -F '[.]' '{print $1}'
    echo MAC: "$2" IP: "$10"
    echo



    fi

    done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very easily in bash. This is fast and efficient:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="22:45:47.349293 00:00:00:00:00:00 > 20:cf:30:39:60:69, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.0.100.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300"

time="${string%%.*}"
tmp="${string#* }"
mac="${tmp%% *}"
tmp="${string%\ \>*}"
ip="${tmp##*\:\ }"

echo "time: '$time', mac: '$mac', ip: '$ip'"
```

output:

```
time: '22:45:47', mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00', ip: '192.168.0.1'
```

Comment: that looks nice :) but how can i modify it to -> time: '22:45:47', mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00', ip: '192.168.0.1' ??? The first mac address should be in the output. I am new in bash programming, my attempts gone wrong.